# How to share a let value (inside *ngFor) from template to .ts

Tags: angular, ngfor

I would like to take the work of pipe async to share the interpolation value {{ticketType.name}} with the .ts component to work with this value. Is it in fact possible?

Here the template code:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let ticketType of ticketTypesQuery.list$ | async" [value]="ticketType.id">
       {{ticketType.name}}
</mat-option>
```

Answer (score 3):

The question isn't exactly clear at the moment, but you could always pipe in any RxJS operator to the source observable in the component controller (*.ts) to use it's notifications.

For eg. if you only wish to use the value emitted from the observable without modifying it, you could use the `tap` operator. Try the following

**Controller (*.ts)**

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

export SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  list$: Observable<any>;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.list$ = this.ticketTypesQuery.list$.pipe(
      tap(ticketTypes => {
        // use `ticketTypes` array emission from the observable
      })
    );
  }
}
```

**Template (*.html)**

You could also wrap the `async` pipe in `<ng-container>` to reuse it's emissions without another `async`. Note that each `async` pipe will trigger an individual subscription of a cold observable.

```html
<!-- Note: we're using `list$` defined in the controller, not `ticketTypesQuery.list$` -->

<ng-container *ngIf="(list$ | async) as list">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let ticketType of list" [value]="ticketType.id">
    {{ticketType.name}}
  </mat-option>
</ng-container>
```